# How to display picture box in the middle of the form regardless of the form's size?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a form with a textbox that is stretched to most part of the form. Then I added a picture box to the form which will be visible on certain conditions on top of the text box by calling BringToFront() on the control.

When I resize the form while running my application, the picture box's location does not change according to the form size. It always stays in one location. Is there any property that helps to keep the picture box always in the middle of the form.

Thank you!

Comment: Use the Anchor property linked to all sides of the form

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Designer, put the picture box in the center of the form. Then use the Anchor property to anchor the picture box on the left, right, top and bottom.

Answer (score 2):

Just adding pictorial guidance refering to @xpda answer

[image: Propert Tab]